# SFDX Command Executor Not Found

Tags: salesforcedx, debugging, sfdx-plugin, plugin-bug

With a custom plugin I've written, whenever I try to run one of my plugin commands, I always receive the following:

```
(node:14344) Error Plugin: mypluginname: command executor not found
module: @oclif/config@1.16.0
task: toCached
plugin: mypluginname
root: C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\mypluginname
See more details with DEBUG=*
```

As a result, I can't compile my plugin.

Can someone offer insight into where this comes from? I have not been able to track down what throws this in the oclif module.